# Ajax call delete cakephp

Tags: html, ajax, cakephp, delete-record

I'm trying to use ajax delete to delete records that, when clicked, confirms before sending the request.
the record is deleted and it work but the problem is after deleting nothing change in the view until after I reload the page manually.
I want to show the result in view just after click "ok" in the dialog

my ajax code :

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  if($('.confirm_delete').length) {
       $('.confirm_delete').click(function(){
         var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
         $('#flashMessage').fadeOut();
         if(result) {
           $.ajax({
              type:"POST",
              url:$(this).attr('href'),
              data:"ajax=1",
              dataType: "json",
              success:function(response){
                }
          });
      }

      return false;
    });
  }
});
```

in view :

```
echo $this->Js->link('Delete', array('controller' => 'publications', 'action'=>'delete', $publication['Publication']['id']),
  array('escape' => false, 'class'=>'confirm_delete'));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if($('.confirm_delete').length) {
   $id=$(this).attr('id');

   $('.confirm_delete').click(function(){
   var result = confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this?');
    $('#flashMessage').fadeOut();

    if(result) {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:$(this).attr('href'),
            data:"ajax=1",
            dataType: "json",
            success:function(response){

                }
        });


        $('#row'+$id).remove();

}


return false;
});
```

}
});

For some reason the $(this).attr('id') does not work  ... how to get id of the element selected to remove it
 I have on my view :

```
<div class="box_detail" id="row<?php echo $publication['Publication']['id']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a CakePHP problem but a JS problem only. If yor delete callback was successful without any error returned you have to remove the related content from the DOM tree. Using jquery this can be done by calling [remove()](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) on any selector you want to remove.

Comment: thank you for your answer .. but can you tell me how do that i try to do this:  success:function(response){
     $('.liste_tab').remove();  and in my view : <div class="liste_tab" > but nothing change
     
     }

Comment: @JOHN strange that should have done it. try replacing your class with an id or just realod the page using js,
something like 
window.location.reload(true); 
or 
window.setTimeout('location.reload()', 3000); //reloads after 3 seconds

in your success function

Comment: if i put the remove in success function nothing change but if i put it after (ajax call), it remove but it show my div empty i want to show all records and hide just the record deleted .. i mean update the div this is code :      if(result) {
            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:$(this).attr('href'),
                data:"ajax=1",
                dataType: "json",
                success:function(response){
     
     }
            });
   $('.box_detail').remove();
     
 }

Comment: i want to fix it without reload my page , any help ?